# How do I float a div to the right of a title div without affecting the content of the title?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'd like to know how to get the following result:

[image]

Green is a container div 700 pixels wide. Blue is a title area which fills the green container width-wise with some title text centred in the middle. Red needs to float on the right without affecting the flow of the text in the title.

How do I achieve this? I've tried floating the red box on the right but it seems to push the text in the title to the left for some reason.

**Edit** - For the record, I hadn't posted an example because HTML and CSS isn't really my area of expertise and I'm struggling to get back to an example where the text didn't align (having tried half a dozen different methods I've been reading).

Here's roughly what I was trying: http://jsfiddle.net/3fgytw0u/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    #Container {
    width: 700px ;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    }

    #Title {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    }

    #GameGuidelines{
        align:right;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="Container">

<div id="Title">
    <h1>This</h1>
    <h2>Is</h2>
    <h2>A</h2>
    <h2>Long</h2>
    <h2>Title Title Title Title</h2>
</div>

    <div id="GameGuidelines">
        <ul>
            <li>Some</li>
            <li>Info</li>
            <li>Here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div id="Introduction">
    <p>Rest of the page continues here</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us that you've tried so far....

Comment: I wouldn't expect such question (without an effort) having such reputation....

Comment: `.blue {position: relative} .red {position: absolute; right: 0; top 0;}` something like this might work

Comment: @DaveGoten no need to use position

Comment: a jsfiddle link, or somewhere to tinker...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the element up into the header, set it to `position:absolute` and give it a `margin-left:500px;`

http://jsfiddle.net/3fgytw0u/2/  <-- that one is right

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help you: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/qaex89p1/)

```
#Container {
width: 700px ;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
position: relative;
}

#Title {
background-color: red;
text-align: center;
}

#GameGuidelines{
    text-align:right;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 200px;
background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: That pulls the game guidelines to the corner of the page not the corner of the green container.

Comment: Ok, prove it [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2vh6p0gp/) I mistake... sorry (and sorry about my english)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach to positioning can be using negative `margin-left` equal to width of red area:

```css
h2 {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #EEE;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h2 .right-block {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: coral;
    float: right;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<h2>
    Some centered text
    <div class="right-block"></div>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want.

```
  <html>

<head></head>
<body>
    <div style="border:green 1px solid;height:700px;" >
        <div style="border:blue 1px solid;width:100%;height:200px;text-align:center">
            Some Title Text
            <div style="float:right;border:1px red solid;width:100px;height:100px;margin-right:5px;position:relative;">
                Some text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Red div will float on the right inside the blue one.

Comment: I tried that but it has the problem I found originally - the title text is offset by the red div: http://jsfiddle.net/t2e2qz1h/

Answer (score 0):

That could be simply done by positioning the inner div as `position: absolute` and putting it `right: 0px`, but because you need to prevent that it does not start to be positioned with the main display instead, you put `position: relative` to the outer div too. Also make sure that while writing you put the red div first and then the div which has purple text, or you can just add `top: 0px` so that you don't care about that anymore.

Then it should work!
Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xg6rove7/

But be wary of the fact that any text in the red box can then overlap the text in the purple, as I have tried to show you in the fiddle. You might b better with using a padding for both sides equal to the box's width, or just use your plain old `float: right`

Comment: In your example, the green div seems to be the width of the page (rather than a smaller / set width)? I've tried setting it to 100 width (for example) but that doesn't seem to affect the output.

Comment: I guess that is irrelevant to the question

Comment: Actually, it is relevant - I did say it was a fixed (700px) width container in the question.

Comment: Well, I've put the red div inside the blue one which is why I think it won't matter how big the green div is. Though, if the green div is too small, as you put it, like 100px, then that might become an issue when it is lesser than width of the red div.

Comment: My point was that I wanted to limit the size of the green box and it's contents. Even if I resize the page to > 1000px, the green box in your example follows the size of the page.

Comment: That sounds quite trivial to me. Plus, it would be good if you could add that to the description there.

Comment: It may sound trivial if you're an expert but I can't see how to make your example do it. I did mention it in the description already "Green is a container div 700 pixels wide".